# Is there a bijection hidden in this relationship?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n>r\geq0$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&X=\{(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n):x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=r,x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\in\mathbb{N}\},\\
&Y=\{(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_{r+1}):y_1+y_2+\cdots+y_{r+1}=n-1,y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_{r+1}\in\mathbb{N}\}.\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I want to establish a practical background to find the bijection between $X$ and $Y$, I understand that solve
$$x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=r$$
is equal to put $r$ identical balls into $n$ different boxes, but solve
$$y_1+y_2+\cdots+y_{r+1}=n-1$$
not seems to be related to this background. Based on observation: maybe I can divide
$$x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=r$$
into $r+1$ cases like that:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\quad & x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=r\\
&\Leftrightarrow x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n-1}\leq r,\\
&\Leftrightarrow
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n-1}=0,\\
x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n-1}=1,\\
x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n-1}=2,\\
\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\\
x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n-1}=r,
\end{array}
\right.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I think this $r+1$ cases has some relationship with these $r+1$ unknowns: $y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_{r+1}$,
corresponding to the equation: $y_1+y_2+\cdots+y_{r+1}=n-1$, there also have $n-1$ unknowns: $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n-1}$ in every cases above.
But I can’t see the essence of this relationship.
So I wonder: maybe there is a bijection hidden in this relationship ?

Comment: Are $x_i$ real numbers or integers?

Comment: It appears that you want to impose the condition $x_i,y_j$ are nonnegative *integers*.  Then it is just [starts and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) with stars changed to bars and vice versa.

Comment: @user10354138 I think the essence of this question is - yes, the two sets have the same number of elements, but is there a sort of "natural" bijection between them? The "stars and bars" argument does not immediately look like it yields an obvious bijection... or does it?

Comment: @StinkingBishop It does.  $X$ "naturally" bijects with all sequences consisting of $n-1$ bars and $r$ stars.  $Y$ "naturally" bijects with all sequences consisting of $(r+1)-1=r$ bars and $n-1$ stars.   Obviously swapping stars and bars is also "natural".

Comment: @user10354138 I see, and I guess this would be very useful for the OP. You may want to write this as an answer actually. I don't know if the OP would like to have some example, e.g. if $n=3, r=5$, the sum $2+2+1=5$ maps onto $**|**|*$ which maps into $0+0+1+0+1+0=2$ etc.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to indicate that $x_i,y_j$ is a non-negative integer, I will modify the original question.